Compute set difference of 2 sorted fluxes
I'm trying to compute the set difference of 2 sorted Fluxes that come from cold publishers.
As I'm computing the set difference I need to hold on to values from the B flux until I see a value from the A flux. However, I want to avoid running out of memory.
I've seen examples using Flux.create where I can use doOnNext to add elements to a buffer from each flux, and then depending on the value decide what to emit if anything. However, as this does not signal any back pressure my memory requirements are unbounded.
I've noticed though that using operations like zip appear to do some buffering and I assume signal back to the producers to stop them generating any more elements until the buffer has space.
How can I do this using project reactor?

You're right that using Flux.create with doOnNext can cause unbounded memory use since it doesn't handle backpressure. To find the difference between two sorted Fluxes without running into memory problems, you can use a mix of Flux.zip and Flux.merge along with some smart buffering. Maybe something like this:
Flux<A> fluxA = ...;
Flux<B> fluxB = ...;

Flux<A> diffFlux = Flux.zip(fluxA, fluxB, (a, b) -> {
    // Buffer to store elements from B flux
    List<B> buffer = new ArrayList<>();

    // Process elements from A and B fluxes
    if (a != null && b != null) {
        if (a.compareTo(b) < 0) {
            // a is smaller, emit it and clear the buffer
            buffer.clear();
            return a;
        } else if (a.compareTo(b) > 0) {
            // b is smaller, add it to the buffer
            buffer.add(b);
            return null;
        } else {
            // a and b are equal, clear the buffer and return null
            buffer.clear();
            return null;
        }
    } else if (a != null) {
        // only a is present, emit it and clear the buffer
        buffer.clear();
        return a;
    } else {
        // only b is present, add it to the buffer
        buffer.add(b);
        return null;
    }
})
.merge(buffer -> Flux.fromIterable(buffer), 1) // merge the buffer with the main flux
.filter(Objects::nonNull); // filter out null values 


So if you want to compare two lists and find the set difference between both lists while saving on memory the best solution is to pass your main ArrayList through a for loop that compares each value with the other ArrayList. If it returns true then you can remove it from said main ArrayList. It saves you from needing to do a lot of wacky things with third lists and whatnot. At the end, you return the new list and replace one of the older lists.
public main()
{
  public static ArrayList<String> set1 = new ArrayList<String>();
  public static ArrayList<String> set2 = new ArrayList<String>();

  set1 = SetDifference(set1, set2);
}

public list SetDifference(arrayList set3, arraylist set4)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < set3.size(); i++)
  {
    if(set4.contains(set3(i)))
    {
      set3.remove(i);
    }
  }
  set1.removeall(set1)
  return set3;
}

If you do not want to have set1.removeall(set1) appear in the FindDifference() method then you can always create a new third set next to the initial two and dump all the info to said new set3 ArrayList.
The following links are what I used to check if a value appears in another ArrayList, remove it from the original list, and remove all values from a list.
ArrayList contains: https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_arraylist_contains.asp
Remove item: https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_arraylist_remove.asp
Remove all items: https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_arraylist_removeall.asp
